# SwiftUI MVVM: child view model re-initialized when parent view updated

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm attempting to use MVVM in a SwiftUI app, however it appears that view models for child views (e.g. ones in a `NavigationLink`) are re-initialized whenever an `ObservableObject` that's observed by both the parent and child is updated. This causes the child's local state to be reset, network data to be reloaded, etc.

I'm guessing it's because this causes parent's `body` to be reevaluated, which contains a constructor to `SubView`'s view model, but I haven't been able to find an alternative that lets me create view models that don't live beyond the life of the view. I need to be able to pass data to the child view model from the parent.

Here's a very simplified playground of what we're trying to accomplish, where incrementing `EnvCounter.counter` resets `SubView.counter`.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

class EnvCounter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var counter = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var envCounter = EnvCounter()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Parent view")
            Button(action: { self.envCounter.counter += 1 }) {
                Text("EnvCounter is at \(self.envCounter.counter)")
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 40)

            SubView(viewModel: .init())
        }
        .environmentObject(envCounter)
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var counter = 0
    }

    @EnvironmentObject var envCounter: EnvCounter
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Sub view")

            Button(action: { self.viewModel.counter += 1 }) {
                Text("SubView counter is at \(self.viewModel.counter)")
            }

            Button(action: { self.envCounter.counter += 1 }) {
                Text("EnvCounter is at \(self.envCounter.counter)")
            }
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Comment: This is normal behaviour. On refresh `View.body` calculable property is called, so any code inside, not hidden by internal state conditions, are executed, so all visible view constructors is called. Just don't put anything heavy in view constructors and/or property default values, move all those logic outside view (there will be bonus - fast UI rendering).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A new property wrapper is added to SwiftUI in Xcode 12, `@StateObject`. You should be able to fix it by simply changing `@ObservedObject` for `@StateObject` as follows.

```
struct SubView: View {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var counter = 0
    }

    @EnvironmentObject var envCounter: EnvCounter
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel // change on this line

    var body: some View {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62544554/12109043) for why using `StateObject` instead of `ObservedObject` changes the `SubView` re-rendering behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

To solve this problem I created a custom helper class called `ViewModelProvider`.

The provider takes a hash for your view, and a method that builds the ViewModel. It then either returns the ViewModel, or builds it if its the first time that it received that hash.

As long as you make sure the hash stays the same as long as you want the same ViewModel, this solves the problem.

```swift
class ViewModelProvider {
    private static var viewModelStore = [String:Any]()
    
    static func makeViewModel<VM>(forHash hash: String, usingBuilder builder: () -> VM) -> VM {
        if let vm = viewModelStore[hash] as? VM {
            return vm
        } else {
            let vm = builder()
            viewModelStore[hash] = vm
            return vm
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your View, you can use the ViewModel:

```swift
Struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: MyViewModel
    
    public init(thisParameterDoesntChangeVM: String, thisParameterChangesVM: String) {
        self.viewModel = ViewModelProvider.makeViewModel(forHash: thisParameterChangesVM) {
            MOFOnboardingFlowViewModel(
                pages: pages,
                baseStyleConfig: style,
                buttonConfig: buttonConfig,
                onFinish: onFinish
            )
        }
    }
}
```

In  this example, there are two parameters. Only `thisParameterChangesVM` is used in the hash. This means that even if `thisParameterDoesntChangeVM` changes and the View is rebuilt, the view model stays the same.

Comment: I went the same way but instead of [String:Any] use NSMapTable<NSString, AnyObject>(keyOptions: NSPointerFunctions.Options.strongMemory, valueOptions: NSPointerFunctions.Options.weakMemory) to remove viewModel on view disappears.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem, your guesses are right, SwiftUI computes all your parent body every time its state changes. The solution is moving the child ViewModel init to the parent's ViewModel, this is the code from your example:

```
class EnvCounter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var counter = 0
    @Published var subViewViewModel = SubView.ViewModel.init()
}

struct CounterView: View {
    @ObservedObject var envCounter = EnvCounter()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Parent view")
            Button(action: { self.envCounter.counter += 1 }) {
                Text("EnvCounter is at \(self.envCounter.counter)")
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 40)

            SubView(viewModel: envCounter.subViewViewModel)
        }
        .environmentObject(envCounter)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an unsafe use of ObservedObject as no one is maintaining the reference to the view model. It works for the CounterView as only that view's body will be reevaluated when the counter changes, but you'll lose state should the PARENT view require updating.
https://betterprogramming.pub/swiftui-the-unsafeobservedobject-quiz-467bb8554262?sk=c6538e3ef0aa458c1436097961b5d042