# What is the difference between ObservedObject and StateObject in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

If I have an `ObservableObject` in SwiftUI I can refer to it as an `@ObservedObject`:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var someText = "Hello World!"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.someText)
    }
}
```

Or as a `@StateObject`:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var someText = "Hello World!"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.someText)
    }
}
```

But what's the actual difference between the two? Are there any situations where one is better than the other, or they are two completely different things?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-stateobject-property-wrapper

Comment: This link actually explains it much better than all of the answers here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject

Answer (score 145, accepted):

**@ObservedObject**

When a view creates its own `@ObservedObject` instance it is recreated every time a view is discarded and redrawn:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
}
```

On the contrary a `@State` variable will *keep* its value when a view is redrawn.

**@StateObject**

A `@StateObject` is a combination of `@ObservedObject` and `@State` - the instance of the `ViewModel` will be kept and reused even after a view is discarded and redrawn:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
}
```

**Performance**

Although an `@ObservedObject` can impact the performance if the View is forced to recreate a heavy-weight object often, it should not matter much when the `@ObservedObject` is not complex.

**When to use @ObservedObject**

It might appear there is no reason now to use an `@ObservedObject`, so when should it be used?

> You should use @StateObject for any observable properties that you
> initialize in the view that uses it. If the ObservableObject instance
> is created externally and passed to the view that uses it mark your
> property with @ObservedObject.

Note there are too many use-cases possible and sometimes it may be *desired* to recreate an observable property in your View. In that case it's better to use an `@ObservedObject`.

Useful links:

- [What’s the difference between @StateObject and @ObservedObject?](https://www.donnywals.com/whats-the-difference-between-stateobject-and-observedobject/)
- [What’s the difference between @ObservedObject, @State, and @EnvironmentObject?](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject)
- [What is the @StateObject property wrapper?](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-stateobject-property-wrapper)

Comment: It is not clear to me if there is any use case ObservedObject at all, why was it not deprecated? @DavidPasztor use case shows they can be equivalent, but when would ObservedObject be the first choice?

Comment: @RyanHeitner Everything is in the useful links I provided. But since it's true that not everyone will read them all, I added the summary to my answer.

Comment: Is it possible for a view to have both?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Yes, these property wrappers are applied to ObservableObject classes, not to the view itself. You can have both StateObject and ObservedObject properties in your view.

Comment: Do you agree that `StateObject` is similar to `State` and `ObservedObject` is similar to `Binding`? So `StateObject` is the owner of the `ObservableObject` and `ObservedObject` is only a (bidirectional) reference to it.

Answer (score 39):

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app) did explain why initializing with `ObservedObject` is **unsafe**.

> SwiftUI might create or recreate a view at any time, so it’s important that initializing a view with a given set of inputs always results in the same view. As a result, it’s unsafe to create an observed object inside a view.

The solution is `StateObject`.

At the same time, the documentation showed us how we should create data models in a view (or app/scene) when it can hold on to the truth, and pass it to another view.

```swift
struct LibraryView: View {
    @StateObject var book = Book() // Hold on to the 1 truth
    var body: some View {
        BookView(book: book) // Pass it to another view
    }
}

struct BookView: View {
    @ObservedObject var book: Book // From external source
}
```

Comment: Would you need ObservedObject since a reference type is being passed into BookView? I'm trying to figure out when you would need ObservedObject.

Comment: Oh, I think I figured it out. Without ObservedObject you will not get any changes pushed to BookView that occur to book if the parent (or other sources) make changes to the book StateObject.

Answer (score 17):

Even though [pawello2222's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62544554/4667835) have nicely explained the differences when the view itself creates its view model, it's important to note the differences when the view model is injected into the view.

When you inject the view model into the view, as long as the view model is a reference type, there are no differences between `@ObservedObject` and `@StateObject`, since the object that injected the view model into your view should hold a reference to view model as well, hence the view model isn't destroyed when the child view is redrawn.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {}

struct ParentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        ChildView(viewModel: viewModel) // Inject view model into child view
    }
}

// Even if `ChildView` is discarded/redrawn, `ViewModel` is kept
// in memory, since `ParentView` still holds a reference to it.
// `ViewModel` is only released, and hence destroyed, when
// `ParentView` is destroyed/redrawn.
struct ChildView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
}
```

Comment: Since you can't make a struct an ObservableObject this seems to be barking up the wrong tree. `Non-class type 'X' cannot conform to class protocol 'ObservableObject'`. Moreover there are differences between these 2 attributes. Owners of an ObserableObject should use @StateObject to avoid it being reset to it's default state when changes happen.

Comment: Actually see the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/63698520/951349 where it is clear that @StateObject attribute preserves state when the parent is redrawn.

Comment: What happens when the parent view is redrawn though? Wouldn't the viewmodel get destroyed there, and any state be lost since it is NOT @StateObject?

Comment: @cabyambo you're correct, the VM should be declared as `@StateObject` on the parent view, updated my answer

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example to illustrate the difference.

Every time you click the `Refresh` button the `StateObjectClass` is  recreated from scratch only for `CountViewObserved`. This means it's `@Published` `count` property gets the default value of `0` when this happens.

The difference between `@StateObject` and `@ObservedObject` is clear. The `@StateObject` version of the observed `StateObjectClass` preserves its state since it is never deinitted. The `@ObservedObject` version does not as it is recreated. So you should use `@StateObject` for the owner of an `ObservableObject`.

```
import SwiftUI

class StateObjectClass: ObservableObject {
    enum ObserverType: String {
        case stateObject
        case observedObject
    }
    
    @Published var count = 0
    let type: ObserverType
    let id = UUID()
    init(type: ObserverType) {
        self.type = type
    }
    deinit {
        print(#function, "type: \(type.rawValue) id: \(id)")
    }
}

struct CountViewState: View {
    @StateObject var state = StateObjectClass(type: .stateObject)
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("@StateObject's count: \(state.count)")
            Button("ADD 1"){
                state.count += 1
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CountViewObserved: View {
    @ObservedObject var state = StateObjectClass(type: .observedObject)
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("@ObservedObject's count: \(state.count)")
            Button("Add 1") {
                state.count += 1
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var count = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Text("Refresh CounterView's count: \(count)")
            
            Button("Refresh") {
                count += 1
            }

            CountViewState()
                .padding()

            CountViewObserved()
                .padding()

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`@StateObject` is a **state** of a given view, thus the instance of it is retained by SwiftUI across `body` updates. It is not retained though when running in Preview.

`@ObservedObject` on the other hand is just an **object being observed** by given `View`, thus is not retained by SwiftUI (it has to be retained outside of the `View`).

In other words - it looks like SwiftUI keeps a `strong` reference of `@StateObject` and `unowned` reference of `@ObservedObject`.

[Retained vs non-retained source](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/), [Previews behavior source](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10149), around ~8:30.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between let's say :

```
@ObservedObject var book: BookModel
```

And

```
@StateObject var book: BookModel
```

`@ObservedObject` does NOT own the instance `book`, its your responsibility to manage the life cycle of the instance..

But when you want to tie the life cycle of your observable object `book` to your view like in `@State` you can use `@StateObject`.

In this case SwiftUI will OWN the observable object and the creation and destruction will be tied to the view's life cycle

SwiftUI will keep the object alive for the whole life cycle of the view

This is great for expensive resources, you do not need to fiddle with `onDisappear` anymore to release resources.

This clarification is taken from WWDC2020 [Data essentials in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/)