# Using an array within a view model

Tags: arrays, mvvm, swiftui

I have an array within a view model.  I cannot work out how to initialise it with dummy data so that I can access any element of the array later.  The number of elements in the array changes each time the view loads so I cannot initialise it in the view model with "repeating".

I tried calling a function from .onAppear to append elements to the array, but .onAppear seems to run after my view has loaded so I get an error trying to access the array.

I'm obviously doing this wrong,

My view model is:

```
class DemoViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var array = [0]
    
}
```

My view is:

```
@ObservedObject private var demoViewModel = DemoViewModel()

// This changes every time the view is called from it's parent
var numberOfItemsInArray = 10

var body: some View {
    List(0..<numberOfItemsInArray) { index in
        Text("Hello, World! - \(index)")
       //     demoViewModel.array[index] = 1
       // causes an error
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I update the newly created array, demoViewModel.array[index] = 1 doesn't work under Hello world.  Also, what is the benefit of @Stateobject?

Comment: 1) You can do this in the `init` of the ContentView 2) See [What is the difference between ObservedObject and StateObject in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544115/what-is-the-difference-between-observedobject-and-stateobject-in-swiftui/62544554)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `numberOfItemsInArray` variable to `DemoViewModel` in init, so you can use `Array(repeating:count:)`:

```
class DemoViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var array: [Int]

    init(numberOfItemsInArray: Int) {
        array = Array(repeating: 0, count: numberOfItemsInArray)
    }
}
```

and initialise `DemoViewModel` like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var demoViewModel: DemoViewModel

    init(numberOfItemsInArray: Int = 10) {
        demoViewModel = DemoViewModel(numberOfItemsInArray: numberOfItemsInArray)
    }

    var body: some View {
        List(0 ..< demoViewModel.array.count) { index in
            Text("Hello, World! - \(index)")
        }
    }
}
```

Also, consider using `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservedObject` if you're using SwiftUI 2.