# Cannot stop Updates with stopUpdatingLocation and stopRelativeAltitudeUpdates

Tags: xcode, swiftui, core-location, apple-watch, core-motion

I am building a paragliding app for watchOS, that can display and log values like altitude, speed, glide ratio and so on.

So far I built the UI, integrated some settings and I am receiving pressure sensor data and gps location.
To save battery life I included a "stop button" that triggers the locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation and CMAltimeter.stopRelativeAltitudeUpdates functions. But in the console I can see still location and altitude updates coming in.

I uploaded the code to https://github.com/LukeCrouch/iAlti/tree/main/iAlti%20WatchKit%20Extension .
The interesting file is probably the ControlsView, here I declare and call the relevant functions.

```
    func stopLocation() {
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
```

I appreciate every bit of help I can get, this is my first time writing an App! :)

Cheers Luke

Comment: Providing the project is a great idea, but no one really wants to click some link and go look at all your code. It's your job to reduce the code to what's needed in order to understand and reproduce the problem and show it here as well.

Comment: @matt I get your point, I will edit my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
@ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
```

Every time the ControlsView is regenerated, that line runs afresh. So the LocationManager is a different LocationManager. So you are telling a LocationManager's CLLocationManager to stop updating, but this is a *different* CLLocationManager from the one that started.

Instead, make this a singleton environment object so that your app has just *one* LocationManager with just *one* CLLocationManager. That way, each time you talk to it, you are talking to the same one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tested it last night with a singleton and it did work! While researching into singletons I also found several articles saying that one should avoid using them at all cost. Whats your opinion on that?

Comment: I'm not saying to use Singleton design pattern with a capital S. I'm saying there must be just one LocationManager even though your View is recreated many times. SwiftUI gives you property wrapper types to ensure that.  That is why I said "environment object". You could use an actual `@EnvironmentObject` here, or you could probably use a `@StateObject` if the only LocationManager is in this one View.

Comment: So just changing `@ObservedObject` to `@StateObject` in your code might be enough. But that is exactly a singleton (small s). It's just that keeping this object alive is done for you behind the scenes.

Comment: Useful discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544115/what-is-the-difference-between-observedobject-and-stateobject-in-swiftui

Comment: I have learned a Wonderful basic discussion about StateObejct & ObservedObject.