# How can I use the data from my class in the ContentView?

Tags: swift, xcode, class, model

Here is where I want to use the data

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("log_Status") var status = true
    @StateObject var parentModel = Parent()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if status {
                VStack(spacing: 25) {
                    Text("Welcome, \(parentModel.dataName)") // <- this data
                    Text("Your email, \(parentModel.email_SignUp)") // <- and this one
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how my model-class looks like

```
class Parent: ObservableObject {
    @Published var dataName = "Username"
    @Published var dataName = "email_SignUp"
}
```

However my View shows me "Welcome,    " , "Your email,     "

I also tried to write

```
@StateObject var parentModel: Parent
```

But XCode asked me to fill SceneDelegate Contentview also.

What should I do?

Comment: Is this a copy paste error or why do both variables have the same name in your class `Parent`? The second ones name should be `email_SignUp`

Comment: Try ObservedObject instead of StateObject

Comment: @Kevin no, it should work either way. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62544554/13087977

Comment: Kevin, tried but it still didn't work.

Comment: @Deitsch, It is about the difference of the StateObject and ObservedObject, Even if I use ObservedObject it does not solve the problem

Comment: StateObject and Observed object are not the cause of you issue

Comment: Did you change things in the `SceneDelegate`?

Answer (score 0):

I've ran this code in XCode and it works.

- are you sure your `status` is true? -> try set it true like i did
- are you sure copy paste error in the class is fixed? (email_SignUp variable name)

```swift
class Parent: ObservableObject {
    @Published var dataName = "MyUsername"
    @Published var email_SignUp = "MyEmail"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("log_Status") var status = true
    @StateObject var parentModel = Parent()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if status {
                VStack(spacing: 25) {
                    Text("Welcome, \(parentModel.dataName)")
                    Text("Your email, \(parentModel.email_SignUp)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Yes I am sure it is true. It shows me "Welcome", "Hello" words

Comment: You can try to create a new SwiftUI Project and copy my code in there. You'll see it works. Your issue is not the code you posted. Did you change anything in your SceneDelegate?