# How to load and save data? - Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swiftui

I was following a tutorial of marking favorites and they left out how to load and save data so if you guys can help that would be great.

Here is my code:

```
class Favorites: ObservableObject {
    
    private var task: Set<Int>
    
    private let saveKey = "Favorites"
    
    init() {
        // load Saved data
        
        self.task = []
    }
    
    func contains(_ sclocations: SClocation) -> Bool {
        task.contains(sclocations.id)
    }
    
    func add(_ sclocations: SClocation) -> Bool {
        objectWillChange.send()
        task.insert(sclocations.id)
        save()
    }
    
    func remove(_ sclocations: SClocation) -> Bool {
        objectWillChange.send()
        task.remove(sclocations.id)
        save()
    }
    
    func save() {
        // Write out Data
    }
}
```

This is the part that keeps crashing:

```
Button(favorites.contains(sclocations) ? "Remove from Favorites" : "Add to Favorites") {
                        if self.favorites.contains(self.sclocations) {
                            self.favorites.remove(self.sclocations)
                        } else {
                            self.favorites.add(self.sclocations)
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserDefaults` is a common tool to use for this. It stores persistent data in a key-value store.

You could use it like this:

```
class Favorites: ObservableObject {
    
    private var task: Set<Int>
    
    private let saveKey = "Favorites"
    
    init() {
        self.task = Set((UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: saveKey) as? [Int]) ?? [])
    }
    
    func contains(_ sclocations: SClocation) -> Bool {
        task.contains(sclocations.id)
    }
    
    func add(_ sclocations: SClocation) -> Bool {
        objectWillChange.send()
        task.insert(sclocations.id)
        save()
        return true
    }
    
    func remove(_ sclocations: SClocation) -> Bool {
        objectWillChange.send()
        task.remove(sclocations.id)
        save()
        return true
    }
    
    func save() {
        // Write out Data
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(Array(task), forKey: saveKey)
    }
}
```

I'd also probably refactor your code a little bit. Using `didSet` on a `@Published` variable seems cleaner. Also, you have unnecessary `Bool` returns on your `add/remove` functions.

```
class Favorites: ObservableObject {
    @Published var task: Set<Int> {
        didSet {
            save()
        }
    }
    
    private let saveKey = "Favorites"
    
    init() {
        self.task = Set((UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: saveKey) as? [Int]) ?? [])
    }
    
    func contains(_ sclocations: SClocation) -> Bool {
        task.contains(sclocations.id)
    }
    
    func add(_ location: SClocation) {
        task.insert(location.id)
    }
    
    func remove(_ location: SClocation) {
        task.remove(location.id)
    }
    
    func save() {
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(Array(task), forKey: saveKey)
    }
}
```

You could even get rid of the `add/remove` functions above and just call `insert` and `remove` directly on the `task` `@Published` property.

---

Another option besides using `UserDefaults` would be to look into Core Data (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata) -- there are plenty of tutorials around for that -- it would be a longer and more involved answer for how to integrate this, though.

Comment: I added a section to my question of a part that keeps crashing in my code. Would you know how to fix it? @jnpdx

Comment: it says "Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Favorites found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for Favorites may be missing as an ancestor of this view." @jnpdx

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is. You've defined `favorites` somewhere as `@EnvironmentObject var favorites: Favorites` but you need to pass in an instance of `Favorites` via `.environmentObject` in a parent view somewhere. See this link for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65754383/560942