# SwiftUI Alert action requires two taps

Tags: swiftui, sprite-kit, alert

The desired action in the following alert (in a SwiftUI View) only runs after the primaryButton ("Yes") is tapped a second time (on the second appearance of the alert):

```
.alert(isPresented: $viewModel.showingAlert) {
                    Alert(
                            title: Text("Confirm your Selection"),
                            message: Text("Are you sure?"),
                            primaryButton: .default (Text("Yes")) {
                                handleGameOver()
                            },
                            secondaryButton: .destructive (
                                Text("No (try again)")) 
                            )
                }
```

As you can see below, handleGameOver() updates two bools in viewModel, which is "observed" by an SKScene where "showingSolution == true" adds a childNode to the scene.

```
func handleGameOver() {
        viewModel.showingSolution = true
        viewModel.respondToTap = false
        gameOver = true
    }
```

**For Further Reference...**

Here is how I have things set up:

The GameViewModel:

```
final class GameViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var showingAlert = false
  @Published var tapOnTarget = false
  @Published var respondToTap = true
  @Published var showingSolution = false
}
```

In the SwiftUI View:

```
struct GameView: View {
@ObservedObject var viewModel: GameViewModel
@Binding var showingGameScene : Bool
@Binding var gameOver: Bool


var scene: SKScene {
        let scene = GameScene()
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 400, height: 300)
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
        scene.backgroundColor = UIColor(.clear)
        scene.viewModel = viewModel
        return scene
    }

var body: some View { ...
SpriteView(scene: scene)
...
```

Finally, in the SKScene:

```
class GameScene: SKScene { 
var viewModel: GameViewModel?
...
```

"showingAlert" is set to true with "viewModel?.showingAlert = true" in "touchesBegan."

I can't be way off, since things work on the second attempt. But clearly that's not good enough.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your question is super vague (and actually I can't even see a question here, what is the question?). There are values you mention (`childNode`, `touchesBegan` etc.) but it's not clear how or where you use them. Please provide a minimum reproducible code that we can try and reproduce ourselves. And also please clarify your question as well.

Comment: Sorry for being vague. I thought that the title, albeit implicitly, indicated a problem that needed to be solved. And I thought that I had, in fact, provided enough context. (Live and learn!) I shall be more careful in the future. In any case, I was prompted by your comment to give things a closer look and I was able to get things working the way they should.

Answer (score 2):

Chastened by a comment from Cuneyt, I revisited my problematic post and was able to spot my error in the process:
In the GameView, I was using

```
@ObservedObject var viewModel: GameViewModel
```

The object is created in the GameView, so I needed to use:

```
@StateObject var viewModel: GameViewModel
```

The discussion at
[What is the difference between ObservedObject and StateObject in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544115/what-is-the-difference-between-observedobject-and-stateobject-in-swiftui)
was helpful.