# How to pass data from a parent model class to a subview in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am having my main view in ContentView class and I do the network call in ContentViewModel class and update a class call User with the response.

My ContentView has several subviews such as HeaderView. When I update the User class properties from the API response, I want to update UI elements defined in HeaderView as well. How can I pass data to my subview (HeaderView) from the ContentViewModel class?

---

I can update the ContentView elements which is pretty simple by setting the ContentViewModel class ObservableObject

```
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
```

and Published the User object

```
@Published var user = User()
```

and update the attribute of user once I received the API response in the same ContentViewModel

```
self.user.name = name
```

where my ContentView has the relationship with it's model class like below

```
@StateObject private var contentViewModel = ContentViewModel()
```

and the UI updates as follow

```
Text("My name \(contentViewModel.user.name)")
```

---

That is the working scenario for ContentView. But I need to pass the value to HeaderView().
My user class is like below

```
import Foundation

class User {
    var name = ""
// more attributes
}
```

Comment: Can you show code for `HeaderView`? Maybe just use `Binding`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the pattern I often use: (note no private var)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var contentViewModel = ContentViewModel()
    ...
    var body: some View {
        ...
        HeaderView(contentViewModel: contentViewModel)
    }
}

struct HeaderView: View {
    @ObservedObject var contentViewModel: ContentViewModel

    var body: some View {
        ...
        Text("My name \(contentViewModel.user.name)")
    }
}

struct User {
    var name = ""
// more attributes
}
```

You can use the same idea with the ".environment(...)" pattern to pass ContentViewModel to all subviews.

Edit: as suggested by @Asperi User should be made a struct.

Comment: Shouldn't `HeaderView`'s `StateObject` be an `ObservedObject`?

Comment: you should use @ObservedObject in HeaderView, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544115/what-is-the-difference-between-observedobject-and-stateobject-in-swiftui

Comment: Combination of @workingdog answer and @Asperi answer works. For a scenario of our main view constructed in several sub views where we do not have direct UI redrawn property, we need the suggestion provided by @Asperi . If you can kindly update your answer with his suggestion (also giving his credit :) ), I can accept this as the correct answer. (since I cannot accept two answers for a single question :D ). Also, you can provide the `.environment(...)` option as another approach which will enrich your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: When you pass the root "View Model" to a "Child View" (HeaderView) the child view cannot be re-used as a component anymore - it pretty much depends on the specific view model. It would be an improvement to just pass the "child view state" to the child view. A child view's "actions" (aka intents, aka events) may be modelled with a function instance (call back) in the child view. The parent view sets up child state and action functions (and handles user actions and other actions send from the child view, which it just sends to the view model).

Answer (score 1):

> When I update the User class properties from the API response, I want to update UI

Independently of how do you pass your model to sub-view it will not update because your `User` is-a *class*, so changing its properties will not activate publishing (because published wrapper holds a reference to User which is not changed) and so view not updating.

Instead you should make `User` a struct

```
struct User {
    var name = ""
// more attributes
}
```

or make it `ObservableObject` as well with all needed properties published and pass by reference to subview observing it in regular way.