# @StateObject vs @ObservedObject when passed externally but owned by the view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, combine

Based on this answer: [What is the difference between ObservedObject and StateObject in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544115/what-is-the-difference-between-observedobject-and-stateobject-in-swiftui)

And the Apple documentation code here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

In SwiftUI app, a `@StateObject` property wrapper should be used when a `View` instantiates the object itself, so that the object won't be recreated during a view update.

If the object is instantiated somewhere else, an `@ObservedObject` wrapper should be used instead.

However, there is a fine line which makes it a bit unclear: what if the object is instantiated somewhere else, but "injected" to the `View` and then the view is the sole owner / holder of that object? Should it be `@StateObject` or `@ObservedObject`?

Sample code to get the point illustrated:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Foundation


struct ViewFactory {
    func makeView() -> some View {
        let viewModel = ViewModel()
        return NameView(viewModel)
    }
}


final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name = ""
    init() {}
}


struct NameView: View {

    // Should this be an `@ObservedObject` or `@StateObject`?
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    init(_ viewModel: ViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.name)
    }
}
```

Based on this article: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject

There is one important difference between @StateObject and @ObservedObject, which is ownership – which view created the object, and which view is just watching it.

*The rule is this: whichever view is the first to create your object must use @StateObject, to tell SwiftUI it is the owner of the data and is responsible for keeping it alive. All other views must use @ObservedObject, to tell SwiftUI they want to watch the object for changes but don’t own it directly.*

it appears that if the `View` to instantiate the `ViewModel`, it has to be declared with `@StateObject`. My code is very similar, the only difference is that the `ViewModel` is created elsewhere, but the `View` "owns" it after the initialization.

Comment: If the view model was created _for_ the view then I make it a StateObject wether it was created inside the view or injected. For me it’s important how you use the view model not where it was created.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Indeed, the view model was created for the view.

Do you have any reference to the official docs or a detailed explanation? Thanks

Comment: Do you use one view model per view or one global view model for all views?

Comment: did you see this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfsA87qRC3Y

Comment: No, it’s only my way of doing it.

Comment: I'm using 1 VM per view each "Screen" owns the VM.

Comment: It should be `@StateObject` in your case - the real question is who is going to make sure the VM is kept in memory in your case only the view can do that as otherwise it would get deallocated once `makeView` function returns.

Comment: Thanks, so the difference between the `@StateObject` and `@ObservableObject` is in the reference counting / ownership, right?

Comment: I would suggest removing the view models and view factories and using SwiftUI as designed ;-) I recommend watching Data Essentials in SwiftUI WWDC 2020

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a really interesting question. There's some subtle behavior going on here.

First, notice that you can't just change `@ObservedObject` to `@StateObject` in `NameView`. It won't compile:

```swift
struct NameView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    init(_ viewModel: ViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        //   ^  Cannot assign to property: 'viewModel' is a get-only property
    }
    ...
}
```

To make it compile, you have to initialize the underlying `_viewModel` stored property of type `StateObject<ViewModel>`:

```swift
struct NameView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    init(_ viewModel: ViewModel) {
        _viewModel = .init(wrappedValue: viewModel)
    }
    ...
}
```

But there's something hidden there. `StateObject.init(wrappedValue:)` is declared like this:

```swift
public init(wrappedValue thunk: @autoclosure @escaping () -> ObjectType)
```

So the expression given as an argument (just `viewModel` above) is wrapped up in a closure, and is **not** evaluated right away. That closure is stored for later use, which is why it is `@escaping`.

As you might guess from the hoops we have to jump through to make it compile, this is a weird way to use `StateObject`. The normal use looks like this:

```swift
struct NormalView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

  var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.name)
    }
}
```

And **doing it the weird way has some drawbacks.** To understand the drawbacks, we need to look at the context in which  `makeView()` or `NormalView()` is evaluated. Let's say it looks like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var count: Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("count: \(count)")
            NormalView()
            ViewFactory().makeView()
        }
    }
}
```

When `count`'s value changes, SwiftUI will ask `ContentView` for its `body` again, which will evaluate both `NormalView()` and `makeView()` again.

So `body` calls `NormalView()` during this second evaluation, which creates another instance of `NormalView`. `NormalView.init` creates a closure which calls `ViewModel()`, and passes the closure to  `StateObject.init(wrappedValue:)`. But `StateObject.init` does **not** evaluate this closure immediately. It stores it away for later use.

Then `body` calls `makeView()`, which **does** call `ViewModel()` immediately. It passes the new `ViewModel` to `NameView.init`, which wraps the new `ViewModel` in a closure and passes the closure to `StateObject.init(wrappedValue:)`. This `StateObject` also doesn't evaluate the closure immediately, but the new `ViewModel` has been created regardless.

Some time after `ContentView.body` returns, SwiftUI wants to call `NormalView.body`. But before doing so, it has to make sure the `StateObject` in this `NormalView` has a `ViewModel`. It notices that this `NormalView` is replacing a prior `NormalView` at the same position in the view hierarchy, so it retrieves the `ViewModel` used by that prior `NormalView` and puts it in the `StateObject` of the new `NormalView`. It **does not** execute the closure given to  `StateObject.init`, so it **does not create a new `ViewModel`**.

Even later, SwiftUI wants to call `NameView.body`. But before doing so, it has to make sure the `StateObject` in this `NameView` has a `ViewModel`. It notices that this `NameView` is replacing a prior `NameView` at the same position in the view hierarchy, so it retrieves the `ViewModel` used by that prior `NameView` and puts it in the `StateObject` of the new `NameView`. It **does not** execute the closure given to `StateObject.init`, and so it **does not use the `ViewModel` referenced by that closure**. But the `ViewModel` was created anyway.

So there are two drawbacks to the weird way in which you're using `@StateObject`:

1. You're creating a new `ViewModel` each time you call `makeView`, even though that `ViewModel` may never be used. This may be expensive, depending on your `ViewModel`.
2. You're creating the `ViewModel` while the `ContentView.body` getter is running. If creating the `ViewModel` has side effects, this may confuse SwiftUI. SwiftUI expects the `body` getter to be a pure function. In the `NormalView` case, SwiftUI is calling the `StateObject`'s closure at a known time when it may be better prepared to handle side effects.

So, back to your original question:

> Should it be `@StateObject` or `@ObservedObject`?

Well, ha ha, that's difficult to answer without seeing an example that's less of a toy. But if you do need to use `@StateObject`, you should probably try to initialize it in the ‘normal’ way.

Comment: Interesting observation. Sometimes I do want to create a new view model when I call `makeView` though

Comment: This answer is a gem!

Comment: Thanks I've been wondering about this issue for quite some time now. Is it fair to say that if we changed `NameView.init` to `_viewModel = .init(wrappedValue: ViewModel())` (so removing the argument that's passed in and creating the view model inside the `@autoclosure`), that this would lead to NOT creating the `ViewModel` each time? (thus `NameView` and `NormalView` would become equivalent if that makes sense)

Comment: It would not create a new `ViewModel` each time, because the expression `ViewModel()` is wrapped in an autoclosure. What you wrote, `_viewModel = .init(wrappedValue: ViewModel())`, is exactly what the compiler generates if you initialize a `StateObject` the “normal way” that I wrote in my answer: `@StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()`.