# @StateObject vs @ObservedObject in a UIKit parent environment

Tags: swiftui, observedobject

I have a banner component written in SwiftUI that I am embedding in a ViewController using a `UIHostingController.view` as a return type in a method:

```
public static func createBannerView(thing: String) -> UIView? {
    let viewModel = bannerViewModel(dependency: SomeRepository(thing: thing))
    return UIHostingController(rootView: bannerView(viewModel: viewModel)).view
}

//I do check for nil, but shortened for readability...
infoBanner.addSubview(createBannerView())
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([...
```

Inside the view, I am referencing the ViewModel as an `@ObservedObject`.

I have heard concerns that I should be referencing the ViewModel as a `@StateObject` instead, because the ViewModel is being created outside of the ViewController. I understand this concern in a situation where the parent view and child view are SwiftUI views, because changes to the immutable parent view will recreate the child view and without the `@StateObject` declaration the data in the `@ObservableObject` will be lost.

But in this situation, the parent UIKit powered ViewController is not immutable, and can change all it wants without forcing a redraw of the child SwiftUI view.

My questions:

1: Is there a benefit in this situation to marking the ViewModel as a `@StateObject` or `@ObservedObject`

2: Is there a danger to marking the ViewModel as a `@StateObject` or `@ObservedObject`

**UPDATE**

An answer on another thread gives a great explanation of how these two objects differ: [@StateObject vs @ObservedObject when passed externally but owned by the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71060365/stateobject-vs-observedobject-when-passed-externally-but-owned-by-the-view)

Comment: Is there something I can add to my response that would clarify further?

Comment: I was looking for more detail. For example: what is the specific difference in function between the two and what specific dangers will you encounter using them in different scenarios.

I found rob mayoffs answer very useful here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71060365/stateobject-vs-observedobject-when-passed-externally-but-owned-by-the-view

Comment: Okay -- I've removed it as you've found your answer elsewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@StateObject vs @ObservedObject when passed externally but owned by the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71060365/stateobject-vs-observedobject-when-passed-externally-but-owned-by-the-view)