# SwiftUI unexpected behavior when animation repeat forever in scrollview

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui, scrollview

I have a strange animation behavior in SwiftUI. I've write a demo to demonstrates it.

I want to animate `CursorView` all time. So I make the `animation` be true when `onAppear` is called.
Everything works fine unless I click the `CursorView`. It will animate the position of `CursorView` because I will hide the `Text View` when `CursorView` is clicked.

The problem is that I don't want the animation of position, I just want the `CursorView` to change the `backgroundColor` during animation.

### Solution

1. Everything works fine if I use `@State var animation`  rather than use the `@Published var animation` which located in the `ViewModel`, but I don't know why.
2. Maybe someone can tell another solution or the reason why 1 can work.

Thanks very much

```
struct UnexpectedView: View {
    @State var activeIndex = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ScrollView {
                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        if activeIndex == 0 {
                            Text("subtitle")
                                .padding(.bottom, 40)
                        }
                        CursorView()
                            .onTapGesture {
                                activeIndex = 1
                            }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class UnexpectedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var animation = false
}

struct CursorView: View {
    @State var animation = false
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = UnexpectedViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 2)
                .foregroundColor(
                    viewModel.animation ? .black : .gray
                )
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)
                    .repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: viewModel.animation)
                .onAppear {
                    viewModel.animation.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `@ObservedObject` to `@StateObject`.

Comment: You're right, but I want to know the reason, can you tell me more detail about this?

Comment: Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544115/what-is-the-difference-between-observedobject-and-stateobject-in-swiftui) (it’s all about ownership)