# .onAppear() doesn't update Shapes that use @resultBuilder

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, shapes

I was playing around with `@resultBuilder` and made a simple result builder called `SumBuilder` which takes a bunch of integers and adds them all up.

```
@resultBuilder
struct SumBuilder {
    static func buildBlock(_ components: Int...) -> Int {
        components.reduce(0, +)
    }
}
```

Since I was also playing around with shapes the other day I thought about creating a custom shape which can use this new result builder in its implementation. The custom shape just draws a line from the origin of the container to the point specified.

```
struct CustomShape: Shape {
    @SumBuilder let sum: () -> Int
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: .zero)
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: sum(), y: sum()))
        }
    }
}
```

When I hooked up `sum` to a `@State` variable in my `ContentView` it works perfectly. However, when I change `sum` using `.onAppear()`, the value of `sum` will change under the hood but the `View` doesn't update to reflect that:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var distance = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Increase distance") {
                distance += 100
            }
            
            CustomShape { distance }
                .stroke()
                .onAppear { distance = 100 }  // << Updates distance, but the View still doesn't show
                                              // the line until I press the Button to make distance = 200
        }
    }
}
```

I tried moving the `.onAppear()` to the `Text` thinking the `.onAppear()` wasn't being called since the `CustomShape` is initially a dot, but that didn't change anything. What's even stranger is that when I transform the `CustomShape` to a regular `View`, the `.onAppear()` works as intended.

How can I make a `Shape` which utilises `@resultBuilder` update even when a value is changed using `.onAppear()`?

P.S. This is only the least amount of code required to recreate the problem. In my real app I'm initialising a variable called `endPoint` to be the centre using a `GeometryProxy`. That's why I can't initialise `distance` directly when I declare it as it would be conceptually different than what I'm actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Weird, but why don't you use `@State private var distance = 100` to init your variable? It is the same as doing it in the .onAppear but it works as expected. Or you can use a ViewModel which holds the distance. This could be set in onAppear and updates the view as well.

Comment: This is just the least amount of code required to recreate the problem I'm actually having. In reality I'm using a GeometryReader and centring the line (along with other things) so I have to update the `@State` from within the body. That's why I use the `.onAppear()` and don't init it directly since it would be impossible to access the `GeometryProxy`. Also, how would your `ViewModel` approach work? Feel free to submit it as an answer or give a short description in the comments

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned, i just tried your code but using a ViewModel, which worked as expected. In production you probably want to use input-ouput-pattern but this is the least amount of code to explain what i meant by using a ViewModel.

```
extension ContentView {
    final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var distance = 0
    }
    
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Increase distance") {
                viewModel.distance += 100
            }
            
            CustomShape { viewModel.distance }
                .stroke()
                .onAppear {
                    viewModel.distance = 100
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `viewModel` should be `@StateObject` since you are creating it inside the view. `@ObservedObject`s __must__ be injected, otherwise whenever they update, they trigger a view update, which recreates them and hence you lose state. See [What is the difference between ObservedObject and StateObject in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544115/what-is-the-difference-between-observedobject-and-stateobject-in-swiftui/62555732#62555732)

Comment: @DávidPásztor, a yes good point.

Comment: `@StateObject` is wrong tool for the job, it's for when you need to store a reference type in `@State`, e.g. to do something asynchronous with lifetime tied to a view, which isn't the case here.

Comment: @malhal right, not in my example but as rayaantaneja mentioned he want to do some other things as well, so he probably need it anyway.

Comment: @malhal The code wouldn't work if you left it as `@State`. For some reason, the shape doesn't update when `onAppear()` modifies the `@State` variable

Comment: `onAppear` is for an external action not for setting state, try simply setting the distance default value to 100 in the struct.

Comment: @malhal In my actual app I am calculating the centre point using a `GeometryProxy` and drawing a line to the centre. So it's impossible for me to calculate the centre point in the initialiser. I *have* to do it in the body because that's where the proxy is available. Is there any way I can update a `@State` variable representing the centre from within the body without using `onAppear()`? `onAppear()` seems like my only option

Comment: @malhal I made a mistake. The property I'm storing is called `endPoint` which must *initially* be set to the centre. From there the user can change it. How can I initially set the `endPoint` to the centre calculated using the `GeometryProxy` without using `onAppear()` and causing a view update?

Comment: You can use anchor preferences to do that https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/03/18/anchor-preferences-in-swiftui/

Comment: @malhal `PreferenceKey`s didn't work but I managed to make it work in my app by adding a `Circle` at the end point. Then `onAppear()` updates the circle and I think that forces an update of my shape as well. Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI, the `.onAppear()` modifier is used to perform some action when a view appears on the screen. However, this modifier does not trigger a re-render of the view, so any changes made within the .onAppear() closure will not be reflected in the view's appearance.

This applies to shapes that use @resultBuilder as well. If a shape is created using @resultBuilder and you make changes to it within the `.onAppear()` closure, the changes will not be visible in the view. To update a shape that uses @resultBuilder you need to use `.onChange()` or `.onReceive()` instead of `.onAppear()` to update the shape which will trigger the view to re-render.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, if I change the shape to a view, the `onAppear()` does in fact cause the view to re-render. Additionally, if I change the `sum` property to a regular int, `onAppear()` does cause a re-render of the shape. Try it out and let me know if it works on your Xcode