# Table Data disappear when try to share selection between windows

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to my macOS app which UI was written in StoryBoard into SwiftUI. I am beginner of SwiftUI...

I have SwiftUI Table like the following:

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Entrant: Identifiable {
    public let id = UUID()
    public var Flags: String
    public var Name: String
    public var Rank: String
    public var Obs: String
    public var Pl: String
    public var Idle: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var dataSource = DataSource()
    
    @ObservedObject var testData: ShareValues
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            ChildView(dataSource: dataSource, aShareValues: testData)
            
            HStack {
                
                Button("Connect") {
                    
                    ButtonsFuncs().connectButton()
                }
                
                Button("DisConnect") {
                    
                    ButtonsFuncs().disconnectButton()
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

ChildView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ChildView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var dataSource: DataSource
    
    @State var entrantSelection: Entrant.ID? = nil
    
    @ObservedObject var aShareValues: ShareValues
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Table(dataSource.tableData, selection: $entrantSelection) {
            TableColumn("Flags",value:\Entrant.Flags).width(35)
            TableColumn("Name", value:\Entrant.Name).width(80)
            TableColumn("Rank", value:\Entrant.Rank).width(30)
            TableColumn("Obs", value:\Entrant.Obs).width(30)
            TableColumn("Pl", value:\Entrant.Pl).width(25)
            TableColumn("Idle", value:\Entrant.Idle).width(30)
        }
        .onChange(of: entrantSelection, perform: { selected in
            // called each time on table selection changes
            
            if let item = dataSource.tableData.first(where: {$0.id == selected}) {
                aShareValues.anOpponentName = item.Name
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This table's selection can be shared using ObservableObject conformed class:

```
class ShareValues: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var anOpponentName: String = ""
}
```

Now, I'd like to share this class between windows.  To do this, I declared StateObject like the following:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TableDataTestApp: App {
    
    @StateObject var testData = ShareValues()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(testData: testData)
        }
    }
}
```

When I run Xcode project and press connect button, I receive table data from net.  But when I select row, the table data disappears.  I don't know why funny phenomenon occurs.  Can anyone help me what's wrong with me...

Comment: You should use StateObject instead of ObservedObject in the ContentView

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, Thank you.  It works like a charm. But I don't know why. I appreciate if you teach me...

Comment: There are so many resources for that, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544115/what-is-the-difference-between-observedobject-and-stateobject-in-swiftui, https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/stateobject-observedobject-differences/, https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject etc, etc.