# Why onChange is not working for child view attributes

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, onchange

I have very simple two views. ContentView and ChildView.
I want to observe child view VM attributes in ContentView VIA .onChange

```
class ContentViewVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var childVM = ChildVM()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var contentVM = ContentViewVM()
    
    var body: some View {
        ChildView(viewModel: contentVM.childVM)
            .onChange(of: contentVM.childVM.isPaymentPresented) { newValue in
                    print("Change Observed")
            }            
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ChildVM
    var body: some View {
        Button("Deep Level Trigger") {
            viewModel.isPaymentPresented.toggle()
            print("Deep Level Triggered: \(viewModel.isPaymentPresented)")
        }
    }
}

class ChildVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isPaymentPresented: Bool = false
}
```

When I click, ChildView Button.

'Deep Level Triggered: true' is printed but 'Change Observed' is not printing.

Comment: Yeah, that is expected behaviour. A `@Published` class doesn't work the way you think. How about having `ChildView` take a callback instead?

Comment: @Sweeper, yes callback will be a good alternative. But can you please highlight that  why 'Published' attributes can't be observed VIA .onChange.

Comment: I think if you change StateObject to ObservedObject it will works. You can learn it there [difference between state and observed object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544115/what-is-the-difference-between-observedobject-and-stateobject-in-swiftui), also I can advice to dive in developer apple on this topics

Comment: @Arsienij tried that also, that's also not working.

Comment: So it is interest that you set child view model as published property, and also it is an observable object. I think it is better to go with EnvironmentObject, or changed ChildVM to some struct with basic property, and then with binding you can listen to changes