# Placement of Async Methods (do / try / await) - Unsure of Usage Location

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await

I'm still far to be an expert in the development and using the MVVM architecture.

I'm successfully contacting an API and accessing the main View if the user is authorized.

Even if in the VM I print properly the user_id coming from the API response, I'm not able to store the data in the @Published var call user.

```
@Published var user: User = User()
```

This is the user structure:

```
struct User: Codable {
    var access_token: String?
    var token_type: String?
    var expires_at: String?
    var email_verified_at: String?
    var status: String?
    var role: String?
    var user_id: Int?
    var message: String?
    //let params: [String]?
}
```

This is my ViewModel

```
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    
@Published var loginMessage = ""
@Published var aPantallaPrincipal = false
@Published var user: User = User()

func login(_ params: String...) {
    Api().login(email: params[0], password: params[1],
                completion: { result, data in. // API call
        
        if result == .success {
            guard let data = data
            else { return }
            
            let decodedResponse = try!
            JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data as! Data)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                if decodedResponse.user_id != 0 { //delfault is 0
                    self.user = User(
                        access_token: decodedResponse.access_token,
                        token_type: decodedResponse.token_type,
                        expires_at: decodedResponse.expires_at,
                        email_verified_at:
                            decodedResponse.email_verified_at, status:
                            decodedResponse.status, role:
                            decodedResponse.role, user_id:
                            decodedResponse.user_id)
                    
                    if (decodedResponse.user.id != 0)
                    {self.aPantallaPrincipal = true}
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
        if result == .error {
            //handle error
        }
    })
    }
}
```

And this is the API call

```
import Foundation

enum ResponseResult {
    case success
    case error
}

final class Api {
    
    
    func login(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (_ result: ResponseResult, _ data: Any?) -> ()) {
        
    let postData = "email=\(email)&password=\(password)".data(using: .utf8)
    
    let postDataString = String(data: postData!, encoding: .utf8)!
    
    guard let url = URL(string: "here my url/endpoint") else { return }
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    urlRequest.httpBody = postData
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        let apiData = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
        print("apiData", apiData)
        if (error != nil) {
            completion(.error, data)
            let errorString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
            print("API COMPLETION ERROR: \(errorString)")
        } else {
            completion(.success, data)
            let responsestring = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
            print("API COMPLETION RESPONSE: \(responsestring)")
            print("usuario ID a pasar a VM", responsestring)
        }
        
    }.resume()
    }
    
}
```

Then in the main View, just to test, and after the login (from the main page) I'm using a button to print the user_id coming from the published var user.

```
print("user: ", viewModel.user.user_id ?? 0)
```

But "user: 0" is always printed.

Additionally, next to the Published var declarations, I can read "

> Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure
> to publish values from the main thread (via operators like
> receive(on:)) on model updates.

"

In the VM, when the response arrivses and result == .success, there I can properly print ("user", decodedResponse.user_id!) and the result is OK

```
user: 85
```

1. I'm trying to use async methods (do / try / await...) but I'm not sure where to place them as I'm not very familiar yet... Any idea?
2. And why in the VM I can get the user_id but it is not storing it in the @Published var?

This is the View from where I'm trying to print the "use_id":

Thanks for your reply @Alexander.
This is how I tried to print the user_id value inside the view:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State var note = false // by means of a button it toggles to true
    var body: some View {
        Modal( showModal: $note, content: ModalContents() )
    }
}

struct ModalContents: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = LoginViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        Button (action: {
            print("user", viewModel.user.user_id ?? 0)
        }, label: {
            Text("Save")
        })
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: Where do you call `login` in the view model and where do the parameters come from? And **never ever** `sync` with GCD. It blocks the thread. As you tagged the question with `async/await` take advantage of that.

Comment: Yes, the solution was pretty stupid but until you ask to the community, you didn't see simple things like this. In the view, I didn't make any call to retrieve the users data. Now is OK!
On the other hand, what is GCD? :)

Comment: **G**rand **C**entral **D**ispatch, the pattern `DispatchQueue` is based on.

Comment: In SwiftUI the `View` structs already are the view model so try removing your legacy view model object?

Comment: Needless to say, feel free to use MVVM pattern in SwiftUI if you would like. Admittedly, some feel strongly that it is unnecessary in SwiftUI, but IMHO it is a matter of personal taste, so do whatever you want. A web search will easily find arguments debating the pros and cons, but this is a matter of opinion, and as such is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

1. 

```swift
final class Api {
    func login(email: String, password: String) async -> (ResponseResult, Any?) {
    ...
    }
}

class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    ...
    func login(_ params: String...) {
        Task(priority: .userInitiated) { [weak self] in
            let result = await Api().login(…)
            ...
            await MainActor.run {
                ...
                self.user = ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. The problem might be in how to refer to the instance of `LoginViewModel`.

`LoginViewModel` must be set to @StateObject at the root or stored somewhere "above", e.g. in a dependency injection classes.

**Also there is no call to `viewModel.login(..)`.**

Comment: I have edited the Post to show it better. Tell me please if you see something wrong when trying to print the user_id value. Thanks!!!

Comment: I have reviewed and tried to implement your solution without success (maybe because I put it in the right place, not sure).
I have edited the Post to show better where I'm trying to print the "user_id" value. Tell me please if you see something wrong when trying to print it. Thanks!!!

Comment: @DavidDev I don't see where you call `viewModel.login(..)` method in your view.

Comment: It’s not advisable to introduce unstructured concurrency. And `MainActor.run {…}` is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Rob can you point to some documentation where it says that it's an anti-pattern? And why unstructured concurrency is not advisable here? The code has no cancel operation.

Comment: See [Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194/). That video walks from GCD, to `MainActor.run {…}`, but ultimately retire that and just isolate the called function to the main actor. As they say in that video, `MainActor.run {…}` is used for the edge-case where you are on some other actor and need to await a series of functions on main actor, this technique lets you do that all with a single context switch. But to use `MainActor.run {…}` as a replacement for our old `DispatchQueue.main.async {…}` is an antiquated, very GCD way of thinking about the problem.

Comment: Re why unstructured concurrency is inadvisable, it is because the (a) caller has no way of knowing when the asynchronous task is done; and (b) this orphaned task has no way to be canceled. Apple repeatedly advises against using unstructured concurrency unnecessarily. One should not write functions that cannot support cancelation. And you blithely `await` `login` and don’t show the OP the change necessary there to adopt async/await. And if you change `login` to use the `URLSession` async `data(from:delegate)` method, it automatically supports both async/await *and* cancelation.

Comment: Okay. So it depends on the client - if it has no cancellation logic, then there is no difference on how to implement the wrapping to the main thread… and, hence, it's not an anti-pattern. I agree, that keeping concurrency structured better though.

Answer (score -1):

A few things:

1. If you want to adopt `async`-`await`, you would start by making `login` in `Api` an `async` method, by using `URLSession` method [`data(for:delegate)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/3767352-data/) rather than [`dataTask(with:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1410330-datatask). Then adjusting the view model is as simple as awaiting this function. See [Swift concurrency: Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194/) for a good, practical demonstration of adopting Swift concurrency.
2. Re the main thread warning, as recommended in WWDC 2021’s [Discover concurrency in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10019/?time=1290), one might isolate the `ObservableObject` to the main actor.
3. Re the user being reset, this might be a side effect of `@ObservedObject`. I would advise `@StateObject` rather than `@ObservedObject` in your `View`. See [What is the difference between ObservedObject and StateObject in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544115/what-is-the-difference-between-observedobject-and-stateobject-in-swiftui/63698520#63698520).

---

E.g.

```swift
struct User: Codable {
    var accessToken: String?
    var tokenType: String?
    var expiresAt: String?
    var emailVerifiedAt: String?
    var status: String?
    var role: String?
    var userId: Int?
    var message: String?
}

final class Api {
    let decoder: JSONDecoder = {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        return decoder
    }()

    func login(email: String, password: String) async throws -> User {
        guard let url = URL(string: "here my url/endpoint") else {
            throw URLError(.badURL)
        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = Data("email=\(email)&password=\(password)".utf8)

        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)

        return try decoder.decode(User.self, from: data)
    }
}

@MainActor class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var loginMessage = ""
    @Published var aPantallaPrincipal = false
    @Published var user: User = User()

    func login(_ params: String...) async {
        do {
            let user = try await Api().login(email: params[0], password: params[1])
            if user.userId != 0 {
                aPantallaPrincipal = true
                self.user = user
            }
        } catch {
            // handle error
        }
    }
}

struct ModalContents: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = LoginViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            print("user", viewModel.user.userId ?? 0)
        } label: {
            Text("Save")
        }
    }
}
```

---

In unrelated observations:

4. Personally, I would do the JSON decoding in `Api` function.
5. I would use camel case properties (e.g., `userId`) rather than snake case found in the JSON (e.g., `user_id`). Set the `keyDecodingStrategy` of the `JSONDecoder` to `.convertFromSnakeCase` to seamlessly do this mapping for you.
6. Be wary of just building the `httpBody` of the request via string interpolation, as certain characters are not permitted and/or will be misinterpreted. You have to percent escape the values or use multipart request. See [HTTP Request in Swift with POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26364914/1271826).
7. The variadic parameters is a bit of an anti-pattern. I would avoid it unless the number of parameters really was variable.
8. This empty `User` technique is a bit of an anti-pattern:

   ```swift
   @Published var user: User = User()
   ```

   I would probably do:

   ```swift
   @Published var user: User?
   ```

   That eliminates the need for all those optional properties inside `User` (and instead, you can have your `User` model really represent which properties are truly option and which are required), nor do you need the tests for `if user.userId != 0 {…}`. You would just `if let user = viewModel.user {…}`

Comment: Too long answer and most of the text is not related to the question (4-8).